# How to plot a shapefile with colors according to a column numbers in R?

Tags: shapefile, r, vector

```
reclass = function(x){
 ifelse(x == 0, 10,
     ifelse(x > 0 & x <= 20, 0, NA))
}
arch$ranks<-as.factor(unlist(lapply(arch$ranks,reclass))
arch.col = topo.colors(nlevels(arch$ranks))
for(i in 1:nlevels(arch$ranks)) {
    plot(arch[arch$ranks== levels(arch$ranks)[i]], col=arch.col[i])
}
```

The above script returns the map that i want but it has no colors. The desired outcome would be to take the 10's in the "ranks" and paint it one color and the zeros and paint them something else altogether.

```
 arch$ranks
  10
   0
  10
  10
  10 
  10
  10
   0
   0
  10
  10
```

I want to make the colors of 10's with one color and the colors of 0's with another. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Please follow recommendations and provide reproducible examples! We do not have access to your data so, either provide a link to your data or use data provided in an R package (eg., meuse in sp) to produce an example that somebody can replicate.

Comment: i added more info, check.

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear on what you mean by columns. As far as I can tell you are subsetting and ploting rows, not columns.

Your "ranks" variable is not a factor so, "nlevels" is returning 0. Replace "nlevels" with "length(unique())" or coerce the data to a factor using "as.factor" rather than "as.numeric" around your call to "lapply".

The reclass function has a syntax error in the second ifelse where there is no argument after the last comma, should be NA.

Your syntax in the subset index is missing a comma that would indicate rows.

```
arch[arch$ranks== levels(arch$ranks)[i],]
```

You probably have and additional issue that you have not come across yet. You should use "unlist" to coerce the results of lapply to a vector. In this case your syntax should look something like this:

```
as.factor(unlist(lapply(arch$ranks, reclass)))
```

Comment: I edited the question with your remarks but i still have the same issue. map with no colors according to the column numbers i work with.Check my edits if you can.